# Accessing a method of a bound service from an IntentReceiver on Android

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I'm having a service class that I bind from my main activity with a `ServiceConnection` to call a method within the service as soon as it is bound. I need to explicitly call the method to pass over the context of my main activity.

If I call this service class from within an `IntentReceiver`, I need to use `peekService` to bind to the service. But how can I spawn it's method then? :-s

Best regards / Thanks alot!
S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`peekService` returns you `IBinder` implementation. you need only to call `getService()` from it and you will get your service object.

Put your code inside your service:

```
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public NotificationService getService() {
        return NotificationService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return new LocalBinder();
}
```

Comment: Vladimir, the IBinder doesn't provide a getService() method. :(

Comment: thanks Vladimir, I did as you said. But the IBinder doesn't give me the chance to call the getService() method. Only the standard IBinder methods seem to be available. What I try to do from my IntentReceiver is: IBinder serviceBinder = peekService(context, bindOAService); OnlineActivities oaServerObj = serviceBinder.getService(); Obviouly wrong, huh?

Comment: you need to cast your obtained IBinder to LocalBinder. Like this: IBinder serviceBinder = peekService(context, bindOAService); OnlineActivities oaServerObj = ((ServiceClass.LocalBinder)serviceBinder).getService();

Comment: well, except for that I can't get over a ClassCastException. :( Eclipse is telling me everything would be alright. I can even see my methods in the list of proposals. But when the casting line is reached LogCat tells me that the receiver could not be started. Is there something else I'm missing?